# Lost my Drive email address- can I access app data off my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, data-recovery, google-apps

I forgot the email address I created and logged in on the Google Drive app on my iPhone.

I’ve tried all the generic troubleshooting steps to no avail (no recovery email or phone number)

I think the only way I can find the email I used is to access the app data to see what emails were used to log into the app on my phone.

Anyone have any ideas on how to go about that? Through iMazing maybe? Thank you all